# Access to SQL Server - query results from a table as another tables query columns

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, combobox

I am taking user input from a series of combo boxes in a MS Access form, which might not all be chosen, so some will be "". But for the responses that are not "", I want to query those columns for the table the user has selected.

For example, this is my utopian solution which I'm I have no idea how to accomplish other than building a query for every possible combination and calling a procedure for that query:

```
SELECT **NON "" COMBOBOX CHOICES**
FROM T1
```

You can talk about the combobox field in the following syntax:

```
Forms![myForm]![myComboBox1Name]
```

The above returns the text from that box, either "" or a string they chose from the options. So in short, I was wondering if I inserted the valid non "" strings from those combo boxes into a table, then somehow used a SELECT statement on the table we could use the rows returned as the fields I want to query, example:

```
SELECT (SELECT * FROM ValidTable)
FROM T1
```

If the resource from the following link were successful, https://www.google.com/amp/s/blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/10/27/sql-server-storing-variable-values-in-temporary-array-or-temporary-list/amp/

Comment: Review http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: Your question is (at least to me) rather confusing. Can you give a non-trivial example of combobox contents and the SQL query you want to result from it? Pretty sure it's easy with dynamic SQL, without any intermediate tables or stuff.

Comment: From what I understand of your request, the link you shared about SQL Server variables is not applicable.  The problem is completely different and the article uses syntax that is not compatible with Access.